# Java how to implement interface with a variadic method and generic return type

Tags: java, functional-programming, generic-programming

I am trying to implement a U.I. where in the user will type a value into the console and my program is supposed to call a function which will either just execute and modify some value or execute and return something. In either case, this function could take parameters or not.

So at this point this is basically sounding like getters and setters, but I don't want to fully implement it in that fashion and this is to avoid having to go through 10+ if statements to determine what to do for any given user input.

So my solution is to create a sort of interface like this inside my class and for each activity I want to run, I create an instance of it using this interface:

```
private interface DoActivity <R> {
    public R execute(Object... param);
}
```

This works for when I don't want to specify the types of the parameters to pass to the execute method, but when I create an instance of DoActivity like this with it's execute method:

```
private class setPerson implements DoActivity {
    @Override
    public Void execute(String name, String telephone) {
        ...
        return null;
    }
}
```

I get an error with the above:
`method does not implement or override a method from supertype`
Is there a way to do what I want without resorting to reflection?

Sample use:

```
// at prompt
>> Enter an operation: 1 Bumble Bee
>> ...

// In program
String input = "1 Bumble Bee";
String split[] = input.split();
int operation = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
DoActivityArray[operation - 1].execute(split[1], split[2]);
```

Comment: Your execute method doesn't have the same type as your interface.  A user isn't (or shouldn't) have a `setPerson` object, rather they should have a `DoActivity` object which just so happened to be instantiated with a `setPerson` object.  From the method prototype, they should be able to put any number of objects they want, not exactly two.

Comment: I don't see that this is a proper use of an interface.  To execute the method, one would need to realize that it's not a `DoActivity` object but rather a `setPerson` object.  This suggests that `setPerson` is different from `DoActivity` and thus shouldn't be equated (which is what an interface essentially means--that the objects represent the same thing but behave differently).

Comment: @Jared `setPerson` is not different from `DoActivity`, notice the `implements` beside the class declaration? This means that `setPerson` is a `DoActivity` object

Comment: 1) Just because you write compilable code using interfaces doesn't mean that you are using interfaces correctly according to OO principles and 2) you didn't present compilable code, so your `setPerson` class doesn't even really exist--something that doesn't exist cannot be an instance of `DoActivity`.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.  It would be helpful to give a sample session to explain the different things you are trying to accomplish.  It sounds to me like what you really need is a `Map` which maps `String`s to objects which take parameters (which themselves seem like would be `String` objects).

Comment: It does help, but I will tell you the problem here will be generics.  How do you _know_ what type the method should return?  You'll have to cast it, but how will you know which type to cast to?  This may not be a problem if you are going to simply output the Object in its `toString` form (as long as that is well defined for all of your objects).

Comment: I was trying to make it more generic, but in essence, the only real return type is `String`. So some methods return String while other methods don't need to return anything as they operate on the params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution, for your particular example, is actually quite easy:

```
private class setPerson implements DoActivity{
    @Override
    public Object execute(final Object ...params){
        if(params.length != 2)
            throw new RuntimeException(
                "setPerson must take an array of exactly two strings");
        try{
            final String name = (String)params[0];
            final String telephone = (String)params[1];
            ...
            return null;
        } catch(ClassCastException cce){
            throw new RuntimeException(
                "setPerson must take an array of exactly two strings");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very close to what I have done, but I noticed that each method should infact return nothing or return a string. So I have changed the return type to be all strings and whenever I call a method, I get it's return value; if it is not null I will print the value returned by the method. Also the `params` is defined as `String... params`

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error is sensible. The interface says the `execute` method can take a arbitrary number of Object arguments but the attempt at an implementation only actually implements the one variant that takes exactly two arguments (Strings, specifically). All of the other variants (exactly one argument, or three arguments, and so on) are not implemented.

In terms of avoiding a big if/else, how about adding a `canExecute` method that returns a boolean. Create a list of potential `DoActivity` implementations, find the first one in the list that returns `true` for `canExecute`, and then execute its `execute` method, which presumes the type and number of arguments.

```
interface DoActivity<R> {

    public boolean canExecute(Object... param);

    public R execute(Object... param);
}

class SetPerson implements DoActivity {

    @Override
    public Void execute(Object... param) {
        String name = (String)param[0];
        String telephone = (String)param[1];        
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canExecute(Object... param) {
        return param != null && param.length == 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good approach, however, I would actually argue that it should now be more of an abstract class rather than interface.  Further, I think the `abstract canExecute` and, I would add, `abstract doExecute` methods should both be protected (they shouldn't be allowed to be called by just any class).  Then you can define the `execute` method by calling the `canExecute` and (if success) `doExecute` method.